# MotionLayout and Horizontal Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I'm trying MotionLayout with an horizontal Recyclerview: with vertical movements the recyclerview was expanded, with horizontal movements the recyclerview was scrolled. But i'm not able to avoid motionlayout intercepts even recyclerview events--> When i scroll horizontally i see that motionlayout intercepts movements and so expand the recyclerview. Is possibile to disable motion layout for all horizontal movements?

Comment: put your layout file and motion scene file